# In Smash Up, is the Zeppelin action ongoing?

Tags: smash-up

The Zeppelin action, from the SteamPunk faction, has a talent to move a minion to or from the base on which it was played. It does not specify "ongoing" in its text, but it seems that this has to be implied with the talent, otherwise it seems entirely useless. Is there any guidance on this?

Comment: It is not ongoing, it is a talent. Ongoing effects are continuous. You can use talent effects once per turn.

Comment: What I mean to ask is if the Zeppelin action remains on the table in play for more than a single turn (like an ongoing action). There are other action cards that specify single moves, but since this is a talent, it seems like it should be usable once each turn and not discarded.

Comment: Actions that are "Play on a base" are not discarded right away. They stay on the base until the base is scored or until they are removed by another card effect. This is not unique to Zeppelin, this is ALL ACTIONS that say "Play on a base."

Answer (score 2):

Talents are not ongoing; they're available for use once per turn.

With that said, the moved minion doesn't move back once the turn is over.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not ongoing. Moving, like destruction, is a one-shot effect (to borrow Magic: The Gathering terminology). The move happens when the talent is used, and that's it.

If it was ongoing, the move would stop when the Zeppelin leaves play. How do you stop something that's already happened? That makes no sense.